# How long it takes for google to refresh the page information? How can I achieve to make it faster?

Tags: google, html, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long before Google will update search terms matching my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7391/how-long-before-google-will-update-search-terms-matching-my-website)

I have a webpage, and I have updated it with meta descriptions and keywords. I would like this data to be updated in Google search results.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Keywords in meta descriptions are most likely ignored. Meta description may be used when displaying search results as a [short desciption of your site](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/de//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) there.

Google updates itself your site from time to time. Frequency depends on your own site update frequency and site relevance - not exclusively, but these are main factors.
The more often your site content changes the more likely it is that Google increases update frequency. Google Bots is adjusting update frequency to nearly fit your update frequency resulting in "fresh" results but not updating much more than necessary.

You can create a [sitemap.xml](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) and define the update frequency for a specific URL, so it may be more likely Google Bot revisits your site on this URL at this time to refresh data. I **assume** Google Bot just takes this info for initial update frequency as an entry point for the adjusting alg described above.

Comment: Meta Descriptions are only used by Google as filler for the page snippet area. Meta Keywords are ignored, they were too easily gamed.